# Android: SEGFAULT of native C++ program that uses static libgnustl

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Device: Google Nexus 7 (2013).

logcat contains

```
I/DEBUG   (  176): Abort message: '@@@ ABORTING: invalid address or address of corrupt block     0x5c6b0 passed to dlfree'.
```

I think there is a problem with static libgnustl. Am I right? How can I force to use  ibgnustl_shared using GNU Build System? I uses android-ndk-r9b installed into $HOME/android-ndk-r9b. Firstly I made standalone toolchain

```
$HOME/android-ndk-r9b/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=$HOME/android-toolchain
```

I wrote simple test that contains shared library and console program that uses it. It crashes on device.

// libtest.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <stddef.h>
#include <string>

namespace test
{

enum { MSG_LEN_BYTES = 3, MSG_LEN_MAX = 0xFFF };
int encodeMsgLength(std::string &encoded_length, size_t length);

}

#endif
```

// libtest.cpp

```
#include "libtest.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test::encodeMsgLength(std::string &encoded_length, size_t length)
{
    encoded_length.clear();

    if (length > MSG_LEN_MAX) {
        return E2BIG;
    }

    char buf[MSG_LEN_BYTES + 1] = {0};
    int cnt = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%03zX", length);

    if (cnt == MSG_LEN_BYTES && static_cast<size_t>(cnt) < sizeof(buf)) {
        encoded_length.assign(buf, cnt);
        return 0;
    }

    assert(!"encodeMsgLength");
    return EBADF;
}
```

// test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "libtest.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: test <number>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    size_t len = atoi(argv[1]);
    std::cout << "encodeMsgLength(" << len << ") => ";

    std::string str;
    int err = test::encodeMsgLength(str, len);

    std::cout << str << ", error " << err << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile.am

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libtest.la
libtest_la_LDFLAGS = -shared -avoid-version
libtest_la_SOURCES = libtest.cpp

bin_PROGRAMS = test
test_LDADD = libtest.la 
test_SOURCES = test.cpp
```

Comment: Why do you think libgnustl is responsible? Do yo see a stack trace that justifies that assumption?

Comment: Because test works with static libtest and crashes with libtest.so.

Answer (score 2):

Build your app using the default : ndk-build --TARGET_PLATFORM android-9

To make sure that only shared library is taken edit your Android.mk and put appropriate library like `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBS := libgnustl`

There are various other tools that you can use to debug your issue:
 1. gdb [search for remote debugging android native app]
 2. strace [ if not directly available use busybox strace ]
 3. valgrind

Also in many cases the memory stack during crash are stores in /data/tombstones. Locate your errror file, pull it and show the details here of the same.

Comment: I uses android toolchain as a standalone compiler and GNU Build System. I do not use ndk-build. The code is tested, valid and works well. If replace std::string in arguments to char*, it will work.

Comment: If build libtest as statis library, test program will work too. The issue is in the stl library usage. Moreover, if use stlport library, this code runs perfectly. But I need libgnustl.

Comment: Sorry, just saw you edited your question.
Please provide the detail crash logs [/data/tombstones/file] or memory print.

Also, you seem to be using standard C library <stdlib.h> etc instead of <cstdlib> in CPP code. Could that be causing the issue ?

Comment: Do not check source code of .cpp files, they have 100% working code. Crash information in /data/tombstones is useless because it's a not a bug in my code.

Comment: APP_STL := gnustl_shared in your makefile shall help I suppose.
Did you try that?
http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html
Also, if it is not a bug in your code that the support for the library in the framework doesn't seem to be proper. Using static library sems to be way to go. Else if newer library has been ported then you may push the shared library to /sdcard and set LDPATH to the directory and run that executable.

Comment: I use Makefile.am, but none of Android.mk or Application.mk. APP_STL cannot be used here.

Comment: @ark1n - you can't push libraries to a -noexec mount like the sdcard if you hope to load them into executable pages on the typical arm-based android devices

Answer (score 2):

Instead of linking to `libgnustl-static.a`, use `libgnustl-shared.so`. Your observation makes sense: when both `libtest.so` and `test` are linked with the static version, then the `std::string` class will have two different `vtable`s, and the program may crash on shutdown. `libstlport` uses internally system stl (always shared) for new/delete, and thus behaves better in your test case. This, naturally, does not protect from other clashes, which may also be lethal. That's why you should use shared version of stl if you use it in two or more dynamically linked components.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I do that in Makefile.am ? I tried -lgnustl, but unsuccessful. Here is libtool output:
    -lstdc++ -lm -lc -ldl -lgcc /home/vadim/android-toolchain/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/crtend_so.o ...

libtool always append -lstdc++ and others libs.

Comment: I don't have r9b installed right now (a fresh computer), but for r9c the standalone toolchain includes `libgnustl_shared.so`. Simply add it to the linker list. If you still have a problem, post the command line that fails (e.g. `make -n`).

Answer (score 1):

In CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html

*"II.3. Static runtimes:
Please keep in mind that the static library variant of a given C++ runtime **SHALL ONLY BE LINKED INTO A SINGLE BINARY** for optimal conditions."*

I had an issue with this where malloc was crashing.

Comment: I read this manual, but I asked how can I enable dynamic linking with libgnustl if I use GNU Build System (autoconf/autmake/libtool). I tried but unsuccessful.

Comment: By the way, why the test program runs perfectly if it was build with statically linked libstlport? Test crashes only with static libgnustl.